"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Products' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. " How to fix this issue in ASP.NET MVC?
I am trying to connect the data with SQL and Visual Studio C#, the databases are connected but my contents doesn't seem in the SQL folders when I try to go SQL Studio. I've added Models and created migration but the problem occurs when I try to execute the app from IIS Express. Can the error occur because of unused classes in the models?
Controller
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public ProductsController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var allProducts = await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
        return View(allProducts);
    }
}

AppDbInitializer.cs
public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
{
    using (var serviceScope = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataContext>();

        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        context.Products.AddRange(new List<Product>()
            {
                //charmlar
                new Product()
                {
                    ProductId=1,
                    ProductName="Kiraz Çiçeği Sallantılı Charm",
                    Image="~/img/flower.jpg",
                    Price=(int)2.519,
                    Description="925 ayar gümüşten üretilen Kiraz Çiçeği Sallantılı Charm’ımız ile baharın ilk işaretlerini kutla. Elde uygulanmış pembe ve beyaz mineye sahip; ışıltılı pembe kübik zirkon ile vurgulanıyor ve kiraz çiçeğimizin üzerindeki yapraklar rüzgârda savruluyormuşçasına hafifçe dönüyor. Pavé kaplamalı halka kısmı, bu olmazsa olmaz çiçek charm’a son dokunuşu yapıyor. Sıcak bir ilkbahar görünümü için diğer soğuk tonlu mücevherler ile kullanabilirsin.",
                    Characteristics="Doğa ve Gökyüzü temalıdır. Derinliği 6 mm,ağırlığı 12,6 mm, genişliği ise 13 mm'dir. Menşei Türkiye'dir.",


                },

                new Product()
                {
                    ProductId=2,
                    ProductName="Sonsuz Kalp Klipsli Yılan Zincir Bileklik",
                    Image="~/img/snake.jpg",
                    Price=(int)2.519,
                    Description="Aileyi birbirine bağlayan sonsuz sevgiyi temsil eden Işıltılı Sonsuz Kalp Klipsli Yılan Zincir Bileklik senin için en önemli olanlar için anlamlı bir hediye. Kafes işi kalp klipsinde, kenarlarında taşlar ve kalbin etrafına yerleştirilmiş asimetrik bir sonsuzluk sembolü yer alıyor. Klipsin arkasında “Family forever and Always” yazısı bulunuyor. Bileklikte, onu üç bölüme ayıran iki diş (yükseltilmiş charm ayırıcılar) bulunmaktadır. Sevdiklerini simgeleyen 16-18 adede kadar favori charm veya sallantılı charm’larınla birlikte kullan veya kalbindeki birine hediye et.",
                    Characteristics="Şeffaf renkte, metal türü gümüştür. Derinliği 8 mm,ağırlığı 10,5 mm, genişliği 12,9 mm'dir. Menşei Türkiye'dir.",
                },

            });

        context.SaveChanges();


        context.Categories.AddRange(new List<Category>()
                {
                    new Category()
                    {
                        CategoryName="Charm'lar",
                        CategoryId=1,
                    },

                    new Category()
                    {
                        CategoryName="Yüzükler",
                        CategoryId=2,
                    },

                    new Category()
                    {
                        CategoryName="Küpeler",
                        CategoryId=3,
                    },

                    new Category()
                    {
                        CategoryName="Kolyeler",
                        CategoryId=4,
                    },

                });

        context.SaveChanges();

DataContext.cs
public class DataContext:DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext>options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts => Set<Account>();
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses => Set<Address>();
    public DbSet<AddressNotebook> AddressNotebooks => Set<AddressNotebook>();
    public DbSet<Basket> Baskets => Set<Basket>();
    public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems => Set<CartItem>();
    public DbSet<Category> Categories => Set<Category>();
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts => Set<Contact>();
    public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards => Set<CreditCard>();
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers => Set<Customer>();
    public DbSet<CustomerPayment> CustomerPayments => Set<CustomerPayment>();
    public DbSet<Discount> Discounts => Set<Discount>();
    public DbSet<EditAcc> EditAccs => Set<EditAcc>();
    public DbSet<Location> Locations => Set<Location>();
    public DbSet<MainPage> MainPages => Set<MainPage>();
    public DbSet<MyAccount> MyAccounts => Set<MyAccount>();
    public DbSet<MyInfo> MyInfos => Set<MyInfo>();
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails => Set<OrderDetail>();
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems => Set<OrderItem>();
    public DbSet<OrderPast> OrderPasts => Set<OrderPast>();
    public DbSet<PaymentDetail> PaymentDetails => Set<PaymentDetail>();
    public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
    public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts => Set<ShoppingCart>();

}

View
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Mağaza";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <img class="rounded-circle" src="@item.ProductName" alt="@item.Image" style="max-width: 150px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>
</div>

Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    var config = builder.Configuration;
    var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("database");
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


AppDbInitializer.Seed(app);

app.Run();

I've encountered a problem during running time after trying to seed my database, in fact I've written Appdbinitializer.Seed(app) in "Program.cs", but it turns out to give a warning. Migration is completed with no problem, I am tring to see my data for both "Products" and "Categories" columns but it doesn't appear. Whenever I try to open the IIS Express, I am getting this issue.

The ProductID column is probably an IDENTITY column in the database and its value is automatically generated during inserts. Change your code to this (Comment the line when you assign a value to the ProductID)
new Product()
                {
                    #ProductId=1, #Comment this line
                    ProductName="Kiraz Çiçeği Sallantılı Charm",
                    Image="~/img/flower.jpg",
                    Price=(int)2.519,
                    Description="925 ayar gümüşten üretilen Kiraz Çiçeği Sallantılı Charm’ımız ile baharın ilk işaretlerini kutla. Elde uygulanmış pembe ve beyaz mineye sahip; ışıltılı pembe kübik zirkon ile vurgulanıyor ve kiraz çiçeğimizin üzerindeki yapraklar rüzgârda savruluyormuşçasına hafifçe dönüyor. Pavé kaplamalı halka kısmı, bu olmazsa olmaz çiçek charm’a son dokunuşu yapıyor. Sıcak bir ilkbahar görünümü için diğer soğuk tonlu mücevherler ile kullanabilirsin.",
                    Characteristics="Doğa ve Gökyüzü temalıdır. Derinliği 6 mm,ağırlığı 12,6 mm, genişliği ise 13 mm'dir. Menşei Türkiye'dir.",
                },


I deleted the ProductId's assigned values and the error changed.  "SqlException: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_Baskets_BasketsId". The conflict occurred in database "ECommDB", table "dbo.Baskets", column 'Id'."

It's a data integrity issue, The BasketsId associated with the Product doesn't exist in the Baskets table. Probably you should change the order in which data is saved.

I named all of the Id's in the models such as "ProductsId", but for the "BasketsId", it's written as only Id. Maybe the problem is occured because of that ?

Column name doesn't matter if mapping is done correctly

Do you mean mapping as model relationships?

I tried to alter Product's foreign key constraints, it is fixed but the same error comes in again.

The problem had solved after deleting the other Id's from catagories. Thank you.

Based on my test, I reproduced the same problem about Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Products' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
You could try the following steps to solve the problem.

Please delete all the tables in the database.

please define it in your model class.


For example:
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ProductId {  get; set; }   

public string? ProductName { get; set; }

3.Please use the following command to do the code first again.
 Add-Migration yourmigrationname
 Update-DataBase

4.Please run the app again and you will find it works well without any errors.

I tried this but it didn't work, there is a problem in seeding the database because when I enter  AppDbInitializer.Seed(app) to program.cs, error happens. Also a problem exists when I try to open the datas from SQL Server Studio, it shows null, no data existed. Do you have another idea?
